# If statement error when working on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a column with values that are negative and positive. If the values are negative I want to add (24*60) to them. if they are positive they will remain the same. I have written the below code but it is throwing an error: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"

I tried .any() and .all() but it is not working

```
    if df_da.loc[i,'Time_diff'] < 0 :
        df_da.loc[i, "Time_diff"]= df_da.loc[i, "Time_diff"]+(24*60)
    else:
        df_da.loc[i, "Time_diff"]= df_da.loc[i, "Time_diff"]
```

Comment: The python `if` requires one true/false value, not multple. It doesn't evaluate once for each row of the Series.

Comment: To address your question on the solution by Yash Sharma, the code you shared works just fine a test DataFrame I made. What line specifically is causing the error? It must have something to do with your DataFrame and the variable `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df_da["Time_diff"] = (df_da["Time_diff"] < 0)*(24*60) + df_da["Time_diff"]
```

This would basically add 24 * 60 to all rows that return True for the inequality.
This will not involve a for loop outside, which I'm assuming there is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy :) It worked. But can you explain why my code didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Yash Sharma's answer.

```
df_da['Time_diff'] += 24*60 if df_da['Time_diff'] < 0 else 0
```

Comment: This code throws the same error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @shravan I'm unsure about the code in your post, but here the cause of the error is quite obvious. `df_da['Time_diff'] < 0` is a Series, `if` takes a single boolean value. The error message `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous` means "I don't know how to judge whether a whole Series should be considered True or False", which makes sense.

Comment: but the funny thing is when I reused the same code in another occasion for the same scenario it worked. That is why the confusion began..if it had not worked in both the cases I would have accepted the above reason :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the source of the error, it would probably require the code for your DataFrame and for `i`.

The currently accepted answer relies on coercing booleans to numbers, and the fact that x * 0 = x. It does not work for most cases and isn't particularly easy to understand.

Here is how I would do this:

```py
neg_time_diff_idx = df_da['Time_diff'] < 0
df_da.loc[neg_time_diff_idx, 'Time_diff'] = df_da.loc[neg_time_diff_idx, 'Time_diff'] + (24 * 60)
```

Which can be simplified to:

```py
neg_time_diff_idx = df_da['Time_diff'] < 0
df_da.loc[neg_time_diff_idx, 'Time_diff'] += 24 * 60
```